# CSS Class with Argument from HTML in Less\Sass\JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, sass, less

I have got something like that:

```
<div class='myclass'>
    <span class='myclass-value-1' value='1'>1%</span>
    <span class='myclass-value-2' value='2'>2%</span>
    ...
    <span class='myclass-value-99' value='99'>99%</span>
    <span class='myclass-value-100' value='100'>100%</span>
</div>
```

I want to create 100 different styles (e.g. different shade of color, or different width - which can be calculable by value from HTML Tag) for every element in `myclass`.
Which way is the best?
Should I use some loop in JQuery, or only Less/Sass could do that? In this case - I want not to use Server-Side template's (eg. Twig's) loops.

Comment: All can do that so the method you need solely depends on why you need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to style the element based on it's attributes/properties then you have to use jQuery(JavaScript). CSS can't use attributes for styling the element. CSS has `attr` function but currently it can only be used for setting the `content` property.

Using jQuery for styling the elements you can use the `css` method:

```
$('span[myclass^=myclass]').css('width', function() {
   return $(this).attr('value') + 'px';
});
```

It's not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve so I can't comment on your HTML markup. It should be noted that both LESS and Sass can be used for iterations. For example for declaring different class names in LESS you can recursively call a mixin:

```
generate-classes(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
  .myclass-value-@{i} {
    property: (@i);
  }
  .generate-classes(@n, (@i + 1));
}

.generate-classes(100);
```

The above snippet outputs:

```
.myclass-value-1 {
  property: 1;
}
.myclass-value-2 {
  property: 2;
}
...
.myclass-value-100 {
  property: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:nth-child(n)` selector to achieve that in your stylesheet.

For reference: http://nthmaster.com/